# Approximating $\bar{z}$ on unit arc

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, weierstrass-approximation

Problem statement: Given a proper closed arc of the unit circle, is there a sequence of polynomials that approximates $\bar{z}$ on the arc?

My thoughts:

1. Well $\bar{z} = 1/z$ on the arc...But the definition of being holomorphic on a compact set is being holomorphic on an open set that contains it? And hence I cannot directly use Runge's theorem.
2. Along this line of thoughts [Complex analysis - $\bar{z}$ cannot be uniformly approximated by polynomials in $z$ on the closed unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794931/complex-analysis-barz-cannot-be-uniformly-approximated-by-polynomials-in), since $|z||p(z)-\bar{z}|=|zp(z) -1| <\epsilon$, this problem is converted into whether we can use polynomials without constant terms to approximate a constant function...That is still not in the range of Runge's theorem....

Comment: the answer is yes as long as the closed arc is not the full circle by Runge theorem for example (or various direct proofs that use Hardy space theory) since $1/z$ is analytic on a small tubular neighborhood of the arc which still doesn't disconnect the plane;  (this has a corollary that any proper closed arc $K$ of the unit circle satisfies Weierstrass theorem in the sense that all continuous functions on $K$ are uniformly approximable by polynomials there as one uses Feijer theorem about the means of Fourier series of continuous functions once we know that $\bar z$ is approximable

Comment: Everything above is subsumed in Mergelyan theorem of course, but that is a fairly difficult result, while these statements are fairly standard and one can even give a direct (but less enlightening) proof of the result about $\bar z$ from scratch without Runge, Hardy space theory etc

Comment: @Conrad Wait, so you mean we can just treat $\bar{z}$ as $1/z$ throughout the solving process? They are not equal in any open set containing the arc though..?

Comment: It doesn't matter since we want to approximate $\bar z$ on the circle arc only so if we approximate $1/z$ in a small neighborhood, we approximate it on the arc and there it is $\bar z$ (note that we clearly cannot approximate $\bar z$ uniformly by polynomials on an open set no matter how small by Cauchy)

Comment: Ahhhh....I see. Thanks.